# Pass additional parameters to a directive callback angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, callback

I use a datepicker which returns a selected date as a value to its callback
the datepicker is a plugin.

In my callback method **selectedDate** i need to pass in additional parameters such as the **dateValue** to this **selectedDate** method. How can i achieve this

```
<datepicker callback="selectedDate" ></datepicker>


 $scope.selectedDate= function (dateValue) {

}
```

Comment: is `selectedDate` in controller? and how the `selectedDate` looks like in controller?

Comment: Yes, I have updated the code with the callback defined in the controller.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/NnhkVvcuAhlVX9v7fxrG?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you need is to specify the kind of params that you are expecting back, http://plnkr.co/edit/0fqMLYlEeBwQylo2Va1B?p=preview

You directive basically asks for the variables on execution,

```
<test-dir callback="callback(a, b , c)"></test-dir>
```

and while execution you pass these values back:

```
 app.directive('testDir', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      callback: '&'
    },
    template: '<div ng-click="testFunc()">click me</div>',
    link: function(scope) {
      scope.testFunc = function() {
         scope.callback({a: 1, b : 2, c: 3});
      } 
    }
  }
})
```